# Catching malware and demonstrate it through windows logs

Tags: security, syslog, malware-detection

I need to catch a virus/malware on purpose on a VM and demonstrate the infection through windows logs analysis. I am using both syslog and eventlog analyzer, but no sign of events logged. I caught on purpose some low level malware (from toolbars installations and browsers hijacking tools). Do i need something more evil ?

Can you guys help me to figure out what do i need to do?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using and what antivirus or other software are you using to detect malware on the system?

Comment: Windows 7 pro 32. I do not have any AV, also the firewall is disabled.

Comment: If you don't have any antivirus software, what are you expecting to create a log entry that will provide evidence of the infection? Is there behavior specific to some piece of malware that you are expecting to be logged?

Comment: I will install the AV to create log entries, thank you. Nothing specific, I'm trying to demonstrate an infection using lowest security settings on IE and a vulnerable version of adobe reader. Do you know any known infected websites?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, viruses/malware are specifically designed to do nothing the user can see including generating log files and/or events in the event viewer.

You would have to change the event viewer to log/monitor all registry,file, and network events and then you would have an even larger problem.  Monitoring like this generates 100's of entries per second.  Your program would then have to sift out of the stream of event the good events from the bad events.

If this were simple anti-virus companies would have beaten bad guys ages ago and they would have give up writing viruses, but it is very complex.

I have setup monitors like this to diagnose miss-behaving programs, but with in minutes you have 100,000+ events which you have to sift through manually.

Then there are rootkits which are specifically designed to thwart even this kind of monitoring.

Try this program, but be aware you will get 1,000,000 events fast.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx